# how to escape the & character in vi

Tags: csv, vi

I'm cleaning data and I have an entry which is "Coconut Bay Resort & Spa, St Lucia" and I would like to replace it with "Coconut Bay Resort & Spa St Lucia".

I am using vi and have tried different ways but not getting anywhere, my first attempt:-

:%s/Coconut Bay Resort &\ Spa\, St Lucia/Coconut Bay Resort &\ Spa St Lucia/g

This gave me:

Coconut Bay Resort Coconut Bay Resort & Spa, St Lucia Spa St Lucia

My other attempts have just given errors, a helping hand would be much appreciated as I refuse to open up the csv I have in excel and use find and replace.

Comment: Try `s/Coconut Bay Resort & Spa, St Lucia/Coconut Bay Resort \& Spa St Lucia/`

Answer (score 1):

As Mark has commented, you can use `s/Coconut Bay Resort & Spa, St Lucia/Coconut Bay Resort \& Spa St Lucia/`.

If you are using NVim, try turning on set inccommand=split to get instant feedback, making search and replaces like this a lot easier to play around with.